# ERROR:Xst:871 - Invalid use of input signal < M > as target

Tags: verilog

Can you spot an error in this Verilog code?
When I synthesize this code, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:Xst:871 - "FA.v" line 46: Invalid use of input signal < M > as target.
```

**Code**

```
 module FA(A,B,Cin,Sum,carry);
 input Cin,A,B;
 output Sum,carry;
 wire w1,w2,w3;
 xor G1(w1,A,B);
 xor G2(Sum,w1,Cin);
 and G3(w2,w1,Cin);
 and G4(w3,A,B);
 or G5(carry,w2,w3);
 endmodule

 module binary(Sum,Cout,V,A,B,M);
 output [3:0]Sum;
 output Cout,V;
 input [3:0]A;
 input [3:0]B;
 input M;
  wire w1,w2,w3,w4;
  
 wire [2:0]c;
 xor G1(w1,B[0],M);
 xor G2(w2,B[1],M);
 xor G3(w3,B[2],M);
 xor G4(w4,B[3],M);

 FA G5(Sum[0],c[0],A[0],w1,M); // line 46
 FA G6(Sum[1],c[1],A[1],w2,c[0]);
 FA G7(Sum[2],c[2],A[2],w3,c[1]);
 FA G8(Sum[3],Cout,A[3],w4,c[2]);

  xor G9(V,c[2],Cout);
  endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The message tells you that you should not connect the `M` `input` port of the `binary` module to the output port of the `G5` instance.  You use connection-by-order, which means `M` is connected to the `FA` `carry` output port.  Therefore, `M` is multiply driven: by the input and by the `FA` `G5` instance.

If you really want `M` to be driven by `FA`, then it must not be declared as an `input`.  It can be declared as a `wire` instead:

```
 module binary(Sum,Cout,V,A,B);
 output [3:0]Sum;
 output Cout,V;
 input [3:0]A;
 input [3:0]B;
 wire M;
```